# Sprite Kit: SKNodes adding to the screen with animation like Fruit Ninja

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Right now I'm working on the game which is similar to Fruit Ninja, I started it with the sprite kit and developed the blade effect (swiping the screen). Now the second part is adding the nodes (like fruits in the game). I tried a lot but didn't get the animation and angle for adding fruit. Below is my code.

```
func createApple() {
     fruitNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "apple")
     fruitNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
     fruitNode.position = CGPoint(x:568, y:50);
     fruitNode.name = "bulletNode"
     fruitNode.zPosition = 1.0;
     fruitNode.size.width = fruitNode.size.width / 6
     fruitNode.size.height = fruitNode.size.height / 6

     fruitNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 60)
     fruitNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =  PhysicsCategory.fruitNode.rawValue
      fruitNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Spiral.rawValue
       fruitNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

       let wait = SKAction .moveToX(self.frame.origin.x -  fruitNode.size.width, duration: 4)
      fruitNode.runAction(wait, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.fruitNode.removeFromParent()
})

addChild(fruitNode)
```

}

Comment: you can't expect anyone to help you if you don't provide any details or code. I (and many others here) want to help, but I simply can't.

Comment: That's not the purpose of SO. Go find a tutorial and try to write your code. If you hit a specific problem then come back, posting the code you have and tell us what you want it to do and what it actually does. We don't know if your sprites aren't appearing on screen, or if they are the wrong size or in the wrong place, if they are not falling, if they are falling but you can't hit them etc etc.

Comment: How can I give the random X, Y axis and move it over the screen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it and working superb...

```
func createPineApple() {
    pineAppleNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pine")
    pineAppleNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    pineAppleNode.name = "pineNode"
    pineAppleNode.zPosition = 1.0;
    pineAppleNode.size.width = pineAppleNode.size.width / 6
    pineAppleNode.size.height = pineAppleNode.size.height / 6
    pineAppleNode.position = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(randomsX()), y:-pineAppleNode.size.height);
    pineAppleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pineAppleNode.size)
    pineAppleNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PineApple.rawValue
    pineAppleNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Blade.rawValue
    pineAppleNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None.rawValue
    pineAppleNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    let xAz = Int(randomsX())
    let yAz = Int(self.frame.size.height - pineAppleNode.size.height)

    let xAz1 = Int(randomsX())
    let yAz1 = Int(-pineAppleNode.size.height)

    let p = CGPoint(x:xAz,y:yAz)
    let p2 = CGPoint(x:xAz1,y:yAz1)

    let randPos = SKAction.moveTo(p, duration: 1)
    let randPos2 = SKAction.moveTo(p2, duration: 1)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([randPos,randPos2])
    pineAppleNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(sequence, count: 1), withKey:  "moving")

    let waist = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock {
        //self.fruitNode.removeFromParent()
    }

    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([waist, run]))
    addChild(pineAppleNode)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the use of Actions as movement of positional values with creating movement via the use of Actions to apply force/impulse to physics objects.

Using Physics objects is a good idea. What you want it is to throw the objects at varying rates and angles from a position below the screen, via the application of forces/impulses to the objects.

There are many tricky parts to this, not least of which is the range of force/impulse sizes to use and the range of angles to fire at in conjunction with this, so all fruit is sliceable. You'll also need to recreate the movement of the "emitter" of the fruit.